# Laravel Valet 502 Bad Gateway when using Eloquent in php8.0

Tags: nginx, laravel

I've got a Laravel 6 application that I'm serving in Valet, I've just upgraded to php8.0 and I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. But curiously only on pages that are using the Eloquent database models, the DB query builder pages seem to run fine.

If I look in the nginx-error.log I have lots of the following error:

```
2022/10/18 10:05:09 [error] 8175#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.test, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/<username>/.config/valet/valet80.sock:", host: "website.test", referrer: "https://website.test/downloads/manage"
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being because I had a package that wasn't compatible with php8, the offending package was sofa\eloquence.